# 「原因{げんいん}」の熟語{じゅくご}の成り立ちは？

Tags: etymology

[Remembering when to use [原]{げん} and when to use [源]{げん}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42227/10859)

をみていて疑問に思った点です。例えば、「原因」の熟語には、「原っぱ」という意味は全くないにも関わらず、「原因」という熟語として成立しています。これは、何故でしょうか。語源は何なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

語源、というより字源的には、「原」の字は山から泉が湧き出ている様子を表したものです（中の形は本来「泉」そのもの）。

[image]

つまり「原」はもともと「源」の意味を含めた「はじまり」とか「もと」という意味を表す漢字でした。「はら」の意味に使う方が（大昔の基準で言うと）当て字です。

なお、「原」が広い意味を表すようになったので、本来表していた「水源、みなもと」の意味に限って、さんずいを加えた「源」の字で書くようになりました。同様に、当て字された単語に本来の字形を乗っ取られた字として「然→燃」、「無→舞」、「景→影」などがあります。

Answer (score 2):

「原因」だけが特別なわけではないと思います。「原」 自体に「物事のおこり、はじめ」という意味があります。

> [げん【原】 の意味](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/69110/meaning/m0u/)
>   物事のもと。起こり。始め。「原案・原因・原稿・原作・原子・原始・原色・原則・原油・原理・原料／起原・語原・根原・病原」

これらはいずれも「原っぱ」の意味ではありません。

ちなみに「語源」と「語原」、「起源」と「起原」に関しては、[どちらもOK](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/77782/meaning/m0u/)だそうです。個人的には語原のほうがしっくりくる気が今はしていますが、深く考えたことはないです…。